# Error installing mySQL in ubuntu - unable to locate package mysqld-server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to install mysql server in ubuntu VM. I tried following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It gives an error saying that some files failed to download.

```
apt-cache search mysql
```

gives no result on mysql-server/mysqld-server

```
apt-get install mysqld-server
```

just gives the output in the title: `unable to locate package mysqld-server`

Could anyone give me a heads up? Thanks.

Comment: Use `apt-get install mysql-server` instead.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu follow the guide here.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```